# Python Popen, any way to read stdout if it does not contain a newline?

Tags: python, popen

I'm using Popen to read a program's output and automatically fill in data, but running into an issue.

I have a program that prompts a user for output.  It is a licensing mechanism for a proprietary product.  It asks basic things like `Does the current date match XX-YY-ZZZZ?` or `Machine limit?`

The issue is that these prompts do not contain a newline character, so trying to use `proc.stdout.read()` doesn't seem to work.

When this application is executed manually, we can obviously read the text in order to respond to it, so if I understand things correctly, this is an indicator of the buffer being flushed.  Is this correct?

How can I read `stdout` even though the prompt from the application does not have a newline in it?

```
def license_code(self, code):
    os.chdir(self.sql_dir)
    print('Current directory: {}'.format(os.getcwd()))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split('bin/dlm -i'),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        bufsize=0
    )

    # Give it 1 seconds
    _now = datetime.datetime.now()
    _response = b''
    while (datetime.datetime.now() - _now).total_seconds() < 1:
        _len = len(_response)
        print('test')
        _response += proc.stdout.read()
        print(_response)
        if len(_response) != _len:
            _now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(_response.decode())
```

The line containing `proc.stdout.read()` hangs and `print(_response)` is never reached.

Comment: So how does your script identify the end of one message?

Comment: A specific chunk of text.  The prompts are uniform and in a specific order.  Sample prompt: `Enter Product Code -> ^C` (where the `^C` is me issuing SIGINT)

Comment: Ah, you definitely can use `read([size])` to read part of the output and analyze it by yourself.

Comment: *sigh* I honestly forgot that `read()` took an argument.  I apologize.  I'm still trying to figure this out.  Thank you.